# need to wait() on async call, but good practice says to not block async

Tags: .net, asynchronous

I just started using `async` and `await` and am trying to solidify my understanding. I want to guarantee that an async function completes.

From what I understand, `await` doesn't actually guarantee that the async function will run (but saves the state and keeps track of where the async function's caller left off).

So to guarantee that the async task completes, I've tried `Task.Delay(1000)` but don't think this is production-worthy code. I was using `.Wait()`, which another stackoverflow post said is bad practice as it mixes synchronous calls with asynchronous calls (`.Wait(), .Result()` are all synchronous blocks).

How can I guarantee the completion of an async call without using `.wait()` or `.result()`?

Comment: Not a full answer, but `.Wait` and `.Result` are ways to wait for the completion. They may not be the best, but they work. The other post likely means that you should generally write your code to allow async calls, but IME there are times when you just need to do a sync call, which is why those methods exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I guarantee the completion of an async call without using .wait() or .result()?

`Wait`/`Result` will synchronously block until that async call completes.

`await` will asynchronously wait until that async call completes.

They all provide the same level of "guarantee".

Answer (score 0):

Awaiting async method:

```
public async void Main()
{
  var result = await AsyncMethodAsync();
}
```

garantes that the result variable will be filled from `AsyncMethodAsync()` when async method ends or exception will be thrown if an exception happen inside AsyncMethodAsync().
Calling `.Result` or `Wait()` do not garantee anything and are blocking your main thread